# How do I get VBA to print a title column for multiple page

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I'm new to VBA, and I'm trying to print a multi-page spreadsheet, but I need column a, which identifies the rows to repeat on each page. I'm pretty sure its connected to the .PrintTitleColumns function, but I can't get it to work. This is what I've tried so far, without success.

```
Workbooks("xxxx.xlsx").Activate
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = False
    .PrintTitleColumns = ActiveSheet.Columns("a:a").Address
    .Orientation = xlLandscape

End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: I couldn't replicate your error.  Try not to use `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveWindow` though - reference the sheet directly by its name, for example. Also, do you need to use `SelectedSheets`? It sounds like you're only working with 1 sheet.